# Where to apply custom middleware for authentication Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my project two type of users, Admin and Normal User. They are identified by the field `isAdmin` in `users` table. User can edit their profile by using the function below

```
public function userEditprofile(){
    $user_detail = userDetail::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $user_detail->address = Input::get('address');
    .......
    $user_detail->save()
    return Redirect::route('showUserProfile');
}
```

and route is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'my_profile'], function() {
    Route::get('/editprofile', array('uses' => 'UserController@userEditprofile', 'as' => 'userEditprofile'));
});
```

Admin can also edit any users profile by using

```
public function adminEditUserprofile($user_id){
        $user_detail = userDetail::find($user_id);
        $user_detail->address = Input::get('address');
        .......
        $user_detail->save()
        return Redirect::route('showUserProfile', $user_id);
    }
```

In both cases action is same but in first method there is no parameter is required. But in the case of admin , a parameter is required. Can I optimize the code by using any other way? I am a self learned programmer. I am not much aware of efficient programming methods.Can anyone reply?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should rather implement role based authorization. A good example has already been implemented by [rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate)

You should actually prefer this boilerplate as it includes a lot that is necessary for most of business applications.